# Building up pressure in the helix coil pump

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, water, flow

My question is about building up pressure in a coil pump. Beginning at the scoop where the water pours into the hose and looking towards the center of the mill wheel, does the coil pump need to have decreasing diameter of each coil? Just as in this picture:
[image: vertical coil pump]

Source: https://youtu.be/mN9iLNHGOYI

Or can the coils be equal size?

The seed of curiosity has been planted by this [River Powered Coil Pump](https://youtu.be/9K1zLVABB0U) Youtube video by Matthew Tiller. In that video all the coils appear to be of the same size. So, how on earth do we have pressure built up through coils of the same size - as if the coils were wound on a spool?
[image]
Source: https://youtu.be/9K1zLVABB0U

The idea of a classic coil pump designed as a spiral on a vertical plane is intuitive. Every next smaller coil gets the same water volume but squeezes the air socket. So ideally the last inner coil gets the entire half volume of water of the most outer coil and gets the air socket squeezed to "infinity".

But how to explain the work of a coil pump designed as helix on a spool? How the air is squeezed in such a pump, if it truly is squeezed?

Key words: coil pump, spiral pump, Wirtz pump

Reference for knowledge on coil pumps:
https://lurkertech.com/water/pump/tailer/